# Contact form take you to new page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax contact form on a site that I recently converted to a wordpress site. The contact form worked fine until I converted it to a wp site. Now it just takes the info you put into the input and creates a new page with it. I have know idea what is going on with it and have no idea where to start.

[You can check the page out here](http://www.spincycleprodcution.com/contact/)

Any experience with something like this happening and/or any solutions?

Comment: There is code outside the `head` in your contact page. Also, the contact form javascript doesn't prevent the default action from occurring .

Comment: What do I need to add to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how things are done in Wordpress or jQuery but your javascript function needs to be changed slightly I think and the code needs to be in the `<head></head>` section ideally.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#ajax-contact-form").submit( function( event ) {
        /* Prevent the form actually submitting in standard manner */
        event.preventDefault();

        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/includes/contact-process.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {
                // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
                if(msg == 'OK') {
                    result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>';
                    $("#fields").hide();
                } else {
                    result = msg;
                }
                $('#note').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And, the path you need to use in your ajax function also needs to be changed - has been edited above. ( I got a 404 when trying just now )

Comment: Same thing with Rasclatt's solution.The new page loading problem is gone but the contact form doesn't do anything now.

Comment: And have you made the changes on the live site so we can see? I can see the function has moved but you have not edited the path as I mentioned... it still returns 404... it should be `/includes/contact-process.php`

Comment: OK, it's still not finding the script - I've tried a few variataions and can't find it

Comment: I'll upvote you because you are right, the file is not where the ajax is looking.

Comment: I fixed it. I just needed to reference back to the wordpress folder rather than the theme folder. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: *phew* - glad you sorted it

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your console *(view source on your page)*, your jQuery for the form ajax is coming in right at the top of your page so the jQuery library is loading *after* you have declared the function. Should land before the end of the `<head>` and *after* the jQuery library is loaded:

```
....etc...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.spincycleprodcution.com/wp-content/themes/spincycle/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                 
// we will add our javascript code here
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/contact-process.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {
                // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
                if(msg == 'OK') {
                    result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>';
                    $("#fields").hide();
                } else {
                    result = msg;
                }
                $('#note').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

Your current console error is:

> **ReferenceError: Can't find variable:** jQuery (anonymous function)

Because you load the function before you load the jQuery library so it can't find the jQuery. You could even load your ajax in the footer....or anywhere really that falls after the jQuery library.

Once you have the AJAX working, you need to make sure the ajax can find the referencing page:

```
contact-process.php
```

Or you receive this error:

> **[Error] Failed to load resource:** the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (contact-process.php, line 0)

Comment: This stops the new page loading problem but the contact form doesn't do anything now.

Comment: That is because it can't find your `includes/contact-process.php` page

Comment: ERROR: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (contact-process.php, line 0)`

Comment: It's loaded up onto the server where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Your ajax is not finding it where you are telling it to find it. That is why it's not working now. I copied the exact error I receive when I click submit.

Comment: It is saying it should be here: `http://www.spincycleprodcution.com/contact/includes/contact-process.php` and with rewrites, I have a feeling `/contact/` is not a real directory

Comment: I fixed it. I just needed to reference back to the wordpress folder rather than the theme folder. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem, yeah, it's hard to tell you where the ajax should look without knowing where in your folder structure you put it.